# NSLocale PreferredLanguages: different results on the same device

Tags: ios, localization

I'm getting crazy trying to figure out how this code could produce different results depending on the project where I run it:

```
NSArray *languages = [NSLocale preferredLanguages];
NSLog(@"%@", languages);
```

On one project (created by Unity) I get "en-FR", "fr-FR", "en-US", on a new blank project I get "fr-FR", "en-US" (that is exactly what I see in my phone lang settings).

I'm pretty sure that `preferredLanguage` reads the user settings information, so I cannot understand how in the world is possible that I'm getting different results with the same device!

Comment: How did you solve this?

Comment: If I remember correctly I was overriding the langs from the unity project settings... that was the "error".